# Setting a 3D environment reference

Tags: c++, frustum, openinventor

I'm setting a Frustum camera to create a Virtual Reality environment that looks like a window when you look at the screen. I've checked all the documentation of the SoCamera, SoFrustumCamera, SoPerspectiveCamera and SoOrtographicCamera, but culdn't find a way to set my scene in order to match its borders with the borders of the screen.

I want to do something like this...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jd3-eiid-Uw

The problem on my code is that the whole scene moves, instead of only the "back" of the scene.
It looks 3D, but doesn't look as immersive as a real window.

Does anyone have a hint or can help me on that? Im making my code in C++, using OpenInventor.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need an off-center perspective camera in order to do perspective shifts like in the youtube clip. Take a look at [DirectXMath XMMatrixPerspectiveOffCenterLH()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.matrix.xmmatrixperspectiveoffcenterlh(v=vs.85).aspx) function. Maybe that'd help.

Comment: I looked for that, and there must be some different setting with the transform positioning that he is using to relocate the center.My Frustum was already set, so it was just a matter of setting the centers in order to match the screen borders